# Create/Update one-to-many relationship models on one page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Can't find an example of this online that doesn't involve creating or updating rows for each individual model on separate pages. I have a simple visitation form, where the overall Visit is a model, with the host's information and other generic parameters. The second model is Visitor, of which a Visit can have many. Relationship works great, I can update them separately.

I've built a request form which I'd like to do everything on one page. Top part of the form is generic information about the visit and the bottom half is a javascript dynamic form section to add/remove visitors on the fly. Form works great, enters the Visit information just fine, but I can't take in the List from the information coming in. Names for them are following the 'Visitors[1].Name' etc etc format.

I've tried adding List Visitors as a variable inside the Visit model, I've also tried a combined custom model, containing both Visit and Visitors. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Showing your code will help us to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I guess this issue may be related with input's name value. Since the model binding will bind the value according to the parameter's name. I suggest you could check the input name to make sure it is match the model binding format.

For example:

If your visit and visitor's class as below:
public class Visit
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string visitname { get; set; }
public List visitors { get; set; }
}
public class Visitors
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string visitor { get; set; }
}

Then the visitor's input name should be `visitors[0].id` , `visitors[1].id`,`visitors[2].id`, `visitors[0].visitor`,`visitors[1].visitor` or else.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        Visit visits;//It is a global variable
        public HomeController()
        {
            visits = new Visit
            {
                id = 10,
                visitname = "visit1",
                visitors = new List<Visitors>
                {
                    new Visitors{ id=19, visitor="visitor1"},
                    new Visitors{ id=20, visitor="visitor2"}
                }
            };
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(visits);
        }
}
```

In Index.cshtml, the changes made by JavaScript to the view may affect the changes of the subscript in Visitors[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNM5u.gif).Name. So the index value should be changed when adding elements and deleting corresponding elements.

```
    @model solution930.Models.Visit
@{
   //Set a global variable
    var count = Model.visitors.Count;
}
    <form action="/home/get" method="post">
        id
        <input asp-for="@Model.id" />
        visitname
        <input asp-for="@Model.visitname" />
        <div id="visitors">
            @for (var i = 0; i <count; i++)
            {
                <div class="visitor">
                    <input name="visitors[@i].id" asp-for="@Model.visitors[i].id" />
                    <input name="visitors[@i].visitor" asp-for="@Model.visitors[i].visitor" />
                    <input type="button" name="name" value="deleterow" onclick="del(event,@Model.visitors[i].id)" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="sub" />
    </form>
<button id="addvisit" onclick="add()">add</button>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var hasCount=@count;
        function del(e, id) {
            if (index == 0) {
                console.log(e.currentTarget.parentElement)
                e.currentTarget.parentElement.remove()
                return;
            }
            location.href = '/home/delete?id=' + id
       }

        function add() {
            var ele = '<div class="visitor"> <input name="visitors[' + hasCount + '].id" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The id field is required." id="visitors_' + hasCount + '__id" value="">  <input name = "visitors[' + hasCount + '].visitor" type = "text" id = "visitors_' + hasCount + '__visitor" value = "" >  <input type="button" name="name" value="deleterow" onclick="del(event,0)"> </div>'
            $('#visitors').last().parent().append(ele)
            hasCount++
            console.log(hasCount)
        }
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  So I was doing this almost to the letter, only using basic javascript instead of JQuery, which I almost thought was the issue.  The problem turned out to be that in generating dynamic rows for my Visitors model, I started the index at 1, instead of 0, so the first one would show up as Visitor[1].Name...etc, etc.

Changing it to index 0, to display Visitor[0].Name, etc, etc, it properly binded after post and iterates through all entries.  Thanks for you help!